# Push segue transition in storyboard doesn't work for iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4

I'm trying to implement a push segue transition for an iPad app between two view controllers using storyboard. I have done it using the same steps as iPhone apps, but push segue doesn't work, it only works if I did it using modal transition. I'm new into iPad developing so I understand I'm missing something.

Many thanks.

Comment: Push segues are for navigation controllers. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a push transition without an underlying `UINavigationController`.

Is your initial view a `UINavigationController`? 
Or is the first view for the segue atleast a `UINavigationController`?